# SQL Server 2016 Issues in Azure disaster and recovery backup

Tags: sql-server, azure

I was running some SQL queries to know why the CPU is been maxed out in Azure after reviewing the performance monitor.

HIGHEST EXECUTION COUNT QUERY RESULT

The following query was determined to be the highest execution with over 500+ executions, once i removed the Disaster recovery, this query was no longer being generated and the CPU resources returned below 70% but doesn't seem to understand what caused it. Please review.

```
INSERT INTO @t
SELECT  
aamd.db_name,
aamd.db_guid,
CASE
WHEN aamd.group_db_guid IS NULL
THEN CONVERT(BIT, 'false')
ELSE CONVERT(BIT, 'true')
END,
CASE
WHEN aamd.drop_date IS NULL
THEN CONVERT(BIT, 'false')
ELSE CONVERT(BIT, 'true')
END,
CONVERT(BIT, aatm.task_agent_data.value('(/DBBackupRecordV2/autoBackupSetting)[1]', 'nvarchar(32)')),
NULLIF(aatm.task_agent_data.value('(/DBBackupRecordV2/containerURL)[1]', 'nvarchar(1024)'), ''),
NULLIF(aatm.task_agent_data.value('(/DBBackupRecordV2/retentionPeriod)[1]', 'int'), 0),
NULLIF(aatm.task_agent_data.value('(/DBBackupRecordV2/encryptionAlgorithm)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)'), ''),
NULLIF(aatm.task_agent_data.value('(/DBBackupRecordV2/encryptorType)[1]', 'nvarchar(32)'), ''),
NULLIF(aatm.task_agent_data.value('(/DBBackupRecordV2/encryptorName)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)'), ''),
NULLIF(aatm.task_agent_data.value('(/DBBackupRecordV2/localCachePath)[1]', 'nvarchar(1024)'), ''),
NULLIF(aatm.task_agent_data.value('(/DBBackupRecordV2/schedulingOption)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)'), ''),
NULLIF(aatm.task_agent_data.value('(/DBBackupRecordV2/fullBackupFreqType)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)'), ''),
NULLIF(aatm.task_agent_data.value('(/DBBackupRecordV2/daysOfWeek)[1]', 'nvarchar(256)'), ''),
NULLIF(aatm.task_agent_data.value('(/DBBackupRecordV2/backupBeginTime)[1]', 'nvarchar(32)'), ''),
NULLIF(aatm.task_agent_data.value('(/DBBackupRecordV2/backupDuration)[1]', 'nvarchar(32)'), ''),
NULLIF(aatm.task_agent_data.value('(/DBBackupRecordV2/logBackupFreq)[1]', 'nvarchar(32)'), '')
FROM autoadmin_managed_databases aamd
RIGHT OUTER JOIN autoadmin_task_agent_metadata aatm
ON aamd.autoadmin_id = aatm.autoadmin_id
WHERE
(
QUOTENAME(@db_name) = QUOTENAME('') OR
QUOTENAME(@db_name) = QUOTENAME(aamd.db_name)
) AND
(
aatm.task_agent_data.exist('/DBBackupRecordV2') = 1
)
AND aamd.autoadmin_id <>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sizing requirements provide a best-guess estimate for the components required to maintain the Disaster Recovery solution.

Each Virtual Server Agent (VSA) instance uses either its physical machine core or a vCPU to process each VM disk and 2 GB of memory to process the stream of data. Multiple disks and VMs are processed, depending on the availability of CPU/vCPU, the availability of RAM, and throttling settings. Performance is driven by the storage transfer medium, the disk speed, and the network bandwidth. You must account for these factors.

**Assume the following number of cores and the amount of RAM for each component in the specified time:**

- **Virtual Server Agent (VSA):** 1 CPU core with 2 GB of RAM can process
  up to 4 TB data in an 8-hour window. This assumes that the necessary disk speed to read and write data and the necessary bandwidth are available.
- **MediaAgent (MA):** 2 CPU cores with 16 GB of RAM can process up to 50
  TB in an 8-hour window. This assumes that the necessary disk speed to read and write data, the SSD space for the deduplication database (DDB) and indexing, and the required bandwidth are are all available.
- **CommServe server:** 8 CPU cores with 32 GB of RAM can run up to 1000
  VMs.

**Replication Sizing**

Assume the following components and factors:

- VM size (s) = 100 GB of RAM each
- Data change rate in percentage (r) = 10%

  **Note:** This assumes a high rate of change. Typically the change rate is 2%–5%.
- Bandwidth (b) = 10 GBps
- Recovery Point Objective (RPO) = 60 minutes

To meet an SLA (recovery time) of 60 minutes, the replication operation must complete 10 TB (10% of 100 TB) in 60 minutes. With 10 small access nodes, 4 vCPUs and 8 GB of RAM are required to read data from the source site and transfer it to the secondary (DR) site in 30 minutes, if the necessary storage speed and bandwidth are available.

After the data transfer is complete, you must account for the time it takes to reconstruct or apply the changes on replicas in the secondary site.
With a 10% change rate, as per the example, with 10 access nodes needed, each access node should have a minimum of 2 cores and 4 GB of RAM to apply 10 TB of data changes to replicas in 30 minutes.

**Design your backup strategy**

After you have selected a recovery model that meets your business requirements for a specific database, you must plan and implement a corresponding backup strategy. The optimal backup strategy depends on a variety of factors, of which the following are especially significant:

- How many hours a day do applications have to access the database?

  If there is a predictable off-peak period, we recommend that you schedule full database backups for that period.
- How frequently are changes and updates likely to occur?

  If changes are frequent, consider the following:
- Under the simple recovery model, consider scheduling differential
  backups between full database backups. A differential backup captures
  only the changes since the last full database backup.
- Under the full recovery model, you should schedule frequent log
  backups. Scheduling differential backups between full backups can
  reduce restore time by reducing the number of log backups you have to
  restore after restoring the data.
- Are changes likely to occur in only a small part of the database or
  in a large part of the database?

  For a large database in which changes are concentrated in a part of the files or filegroups, partial backups and or file backups can be useful. For more information, see Partial Backups (SQL Server) and Full File Backups (SQL Server).
- How much disk space will a full database backup require?
- How far in the past does your business require to maintain backups?

Make sure you have a proper backup schedule established according to the needs of the application and business requirements. As the backups get old, the risk of data loss is higher unless you have a way to regenerate all the data till the point of failure. Before you choose to dispose of old backups due to storage resource limitations, consider if recoverability is required that far in the past

**Useful links:**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-and-restore-of-sql-server-databases?view=sql-server-ver15
- https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/blog/sql-server-disaster-recovery-plan/
- https://www.sqlshack.com/useful-considerations-for-sql-server-disaster-recovery/